# Cannot pass string to IN clause in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that takes one parameter and I need to use that in my `IN` clause, but that does not work. I get this error when trying.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int

Here is my stored procedure..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetSegment] 
    @SegmentIds nVarChar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT dbo.Segment.Name
    FROM dbo.tbl_Category  
    INNER JOIN dbo.Segment ON dbo.tbl_Category.SegmentId
    WHERE (dbo.Segment.Id IN (@SegmentIds))
```

I pass in "1,2". How can I make this work?

Comment: `IN` works on a list of values. `@Segmentids` is a single value, no matter what it contains. If you want to use multiple values you can use STRING_SPLIT which is available in all supported SQL Server versions, or use [a table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) and pass a table with those values to the stored procedure. How you do that depends on the client. In T-SQL you can create a table variable with `declare @ids table (id int)`

Comment: What is the client? Another T-SQL script? A .NET program? Something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) Converting to `int` shouldn't be a big leap beyond the answers provided.

Comment: String_split does not work in sql server 2008. I tried by executing the stored procedure. Anyway, I got a solution that worked below. I will then use this stored procedure in a .net webb application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016+, you can use `string_split()`:

```
WHERE dbo.Segment.Id IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SegmentIds, ','))
```

You can use any string split function for this purpose.  You can also just use `like:

```
where ',' + @SegmentIds + ',' like '%,' + convert(varchar(255), dbo.Segment.Id) + ',%'
```

Comment: Great function but I have SQL Server 2008 so cannot use that one

Comment: @MTplus . . . What are you using unsupported software?

Comment: @MTplus did you solved your problem using the LIKE statement? instead of looking for a best suitable solutions? does the LIKE statement didnt punish the performance?
I'm still looking for your answer

Comment: Hi, I went for the like solution. I have not measured performance though so cant tell how that is.